# How to concatenate a backslash between two variables?

Tags: php, concatenation

I want to concatenate a backslash between two variables when passing them in the arguments of a function so they form a filepath.

```
turbo_function($variable1.\.$variable2, $otherargument);
```

I'm sure the backslash needs to be escaped. I've tried wrapping it in quotes and double quotes.

**How can I concatenate the backslash to the variables successfully?**

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly it should simply be something like this: `turbo_function($variable1 . "\\" . $variable2, $otherargument);`

Comment: Please show your code.?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the backslash with a backslash !

Like this..

```
turbo_function($variable1."\\".$variable2, $otherargument);
```

Answer (score 4):

1. It needs to be a string
2. It is an escape character, so inside a string it must be escaped

Such:

```
$variable1 . "\\" . $variable2
```

Answer (score 0):

The backslash needs to a string and it needs to escaped with another backslash. Here's how you can do this:

```
$concatinatedVar = $variable1."\\".$variable2;
turbo_function($concatinatedVar , $otherargument);
```